# Не получается склеить frontend и backend

Tags: html, java-ee, servlet, tomcat, electron

Пишу desktop приложение, где frontend написан на **HTML**+**CSS**+(немножко)**JS** с использованием фреймворка **Electron**. backend пишется на **Java**: сервлет принимает данные обрабатывает их и отсылает назад на форму.
С **Java** работаю в **Eclipse**, поставил **Tomcat**. Проблема в следующем : Я не могу, грубо говоря, склеить это, не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы по кнопочке данные уходили на мой сервлет и не могу найти инфу чтобы почитать и разобраться, какие технологии и как их нужно использовать и тд. Очень буду рад любой помощи, совету и малейшей ниточке, ведущей к знаниям!)